# replace three carriage returns with two

Tags: regex, string, actionscript-3

I have a text that has this structure

line1: Sometext(followed by carriage return)

line2: more text(followed by carriage return)

line3: more text(followed by carriage return)

line4: Carriage Return (\r)(followed by carriage return)

line5: Carriage Return (\r)(followed by carriage return)

line6: new text and so on

How can I replace the three carriage returns in lines (3 through 5) with something else?

I tried

```
var removeCR: RegExp = /[\r\n]+/g;
```

but that did not work. 
Any ideas. Thank you

Comment: If I understand correctly, you wish to replace multiple CR with a single one? If so, try using `/[\r\n]{2,}/g`

Comment: Yes, I want to replace three carriage returns with something else

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you so much. What if I wanted to do two regex replacements. Would I use two separate regex vars or is there a way to combine them. Or should I create a new question

Comment: @HarshPoddar: You might want to post an answer. FlashV8, use `@` + user name to notify them of your feedback.

Comment: @FlashV8 What kind of regex replacements are you talking about? I know at times, there is an issue when you try and replace two regex matches next to each other that overlap (even if you use a non-catching group). Depending on the kind of replacement you which to do, the answer will vary. I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str.replace(/[\r\n]{3}/g, "something else");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following regex `/[\r\n]{3,}/g`

For future reference, I recommend checking out the following website for regex:

https://regex101.com/r/fA3oO3/1

Comment: @HarshPoddarThank you for your earlier response and this one as well!

Answer (score 0):

To replace empty lines, you could come up with this:

```
^$
```

Apparently, this will only work in `multiline` mode.